# Upload image after clicking on submit button, not on input change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cloudinary, supabase

I want to create a form that uploads the images to Cloudinary and then gets the image's URL and parses it into Supabase database, but I only want to upload the images when I click the **Publish** button (right now the image will auto upload when I selected it).

So I wondering how I can create a function for that purpose. Please help! Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
'use client';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter, redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { useUser } from '@/contexts/AuthContext';
import { Database } from '@/db_types'
import Button from "@/components/shared/Button"
import Editor from "@/components/shared/Editor"

type Posts = Database['public']['Tables']['posts']['Row']

const initialState = {
  title: "",
  description: "",
  slug: "",
  images: "",
};

export default function AddPost() {

  const { userDetails , supabase } = useUser();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [title, setTitle] = useState<Posts['title']>(null)
  const [description, setDescription] = useState<Posts['description']>(null)
  const [slug, setSlug] = useState<Posts['slug']>(null)
  const [user_id] = useState<Posts['user_id']>(null)
  const [images, setImages] = useState<Posts['images']>(null)
  const [imageData, setImageData] = useState(initialState);


  if (!userDetails) {
    redirect('/login');
  }


  const uploadImage = async (e : any) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
    };
    if (!e.target.files || e.target.files.length === 0) {
      throw new Error('You must select an image to upload.')
    }

    const files = e.target.files[0]
    if (!files) return;
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", files);
    data.append("upload_preset", "c_tags");
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_API}`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }
    );
    const file = await res.json();
    setImageData({ ...imageData, images: file.secure_url });
    setLoading(false);
  };

  async function addPost({
    title,
    description,
    slug,
    images,
    user_id,
  }: {
    title: Posts['title']
    description: Posts['description']
    slug: Posts['slug']
    images: Posts['images']
    user_id: Posts['user_id'] 
  }) {
    try {
        setLoading(true)
        

        
        const updates = {
          title,
          description,
          slug,
          images : `${imageData.images}`,
          created_at: new Date().toISOString(),
          user_id: userDetails?.id
        }

        let { error } = await supabase.from('posts').upsert(updates)
        if (error) throw error
        alert('Published!')
        } catch (error) {
        alert('Error updating the data!')
        console.log(error)
        } finally {
        setLoading(false)
        }
    }
   
  return (
    <div className="">
      <div>
      <form
          className="mt-3"
          onSubmit={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            addPost({ title, description, slug, images, user_id })
          }}
        >
        <input
          id="images"
          type="file"
          className="relative block w-full appearance-none rounded-none rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:z-10 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={uploadImage}
        />

        <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
        <input
          id="title"
          type="text"
          className="relative block w-full appearance-none rounded-none rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:z-10 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
          value={title || ''}
          onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
   
        
        <label htmlFor="Description">Content</label>
        <Editor
            description={description}
            setDescription={setDescription}
        />
    
        <label htmlFor="slug">Slug</label>
        <input
          id="slug"
          type="text"
          className="relative block w-full appearance-none rounded-none rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:z-10 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
          value={slug || ''}
          onChange={(e) => setSlug(e.target.value)}
        />
          <div>
          <Button
            className="mt-5 bg-red-500"
            onClick={() => addPost({ title, description, slug, user_id, images })}
          >
            Publish
          </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload the image after clicking on Publish button, you could simply move the uploading part inside `addPost`, aka remove `uploadImage`, and handle everything in one place, on `submit`.

For that, set an `imageInputRef`:

```
const imageInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
```

Add it to your upload input (notice the `onChange` is removed):

```
<input
  id="images"
  type="file"
  className="relative block w-full appearance-none rounded-none rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:z-10 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
  accept="image/*"
  ref={imageInputRef}
/>
```

Change your Publish button as below (notice the `onClick` is removed, and a `type=submit` is added):

```
<Button type="sumbit" className="mt-5 bg-red-500">
  Publish
</Button>
```

And finally, remove `uploadImage` and change `addPost` to:

```
async function addPost({
  title,
  description,
  slug,
}: {
  title: Posts["title"];
  description: Posts["description"];
  slug: Posts["slug"];
  images: Posts['images'];
  user_id: Posts["user_id"];
}) {
  try {
    if (!imageInputRef.current?.files || imageInputRef.current?.files.length === 0) {
      // You could set some error message in a state here.
      return;
    }

    setLoading(true);

    const file = imageInputRef.current.files[0];
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", file);
    data.append("upload_preset", "c_tags");

    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_API}`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
    });
    const returnedFile = await res.json();

    const newImageData = { ...imageData, images: returnedFile.secure_url };
    setImageData(newImageData);
    const updates = {
      title,
      description,
      slug,
      images: `${newImageData.images}`,
      created_at: new Date().toISOString(),
      user_id: userDetails?.id,
    };

    let { error } = await supabase.from("posts").upsert(updates);
    if (error) throw error;
    alert("Published!");
  } catch (error) {
    alert("Error updating the data!");
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by creating a separate state for storing the image until you click the publish button.

```
const [imgState, setImgState] = useState(null);

function onImgAdd(e){
// for input type file
setImgState(e.target.files[0])
}

function onPublishClick(){
// use upload logic for the file, use
uploadFunction(imgState)
}
```

This also gives you an easier way if you want to show a preview before publishing without having to actually upload it by creating a local url which is a common feature in a lot of web apps and you might end up needing it later on.

```
// Its a simple url that you can add as src of an img tag
const url = URL.createObjectURL(imgState);
```